# JavaScript Iterate Multiple Nested Sets

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, for-loop

I am building a PhoneGap "app" (find it difficult to troubleshoot what is and inst working) and have some dynamic JSON results that have a few different subsets that i need to iterate on in order to display an easy to understand page.

The data looks like this (as an example) there could be multiple, single or none in some of the subsets country1/country2

```
{
months: [
  {
  index: 201602,
  year: "2016",
  mon: "February",
  country1: [
  {
    index: 12345678,
    l: [
      {
      name: "Test1",
      mname: "Test 1",
      net: "February 10, 2016 11:39:00 UTC",
      }
    ]
    },
    {
    index: 23456789,
    l: [
      {
      name: "Test2",
      mname: "Test 2",
      net: "February 10, 2016 11:39:00 UTC",
      }
    ]
    }
  ],
  country2: [ ]
},
{
index: 201603,
year: "2016",
mon: "March",
country1: [
{
    index: 546547657654,
    l: [
      {
      name: "Test1",
      mname: "Test 1",
      net: "March 10, 2016 11:39:00 UTC",
      }
    ]
}
],
country2: []
},
{
index: 201604,
year: "2016",
mon: "April",
country1: [ ],
country2: [
{
    index: 78676756,
    l: [
      {
      name: "Test1",
      mname: "Test 1",
      net: "April10, 2016 11:39:00 UTC",
      }
    ]
}
]
}
]
}
```

I am able to JSON.parse it into a variable and when i console.log it out i get

```
 { months:
   [ { index: 201602,
       year: '2016',
       mon: 'February',
       launches: [Object],
       tbds: [Object] },
     { index: 201603,
       year: '2016',
       mon: 'March',
       launches: [],
       tbds: [Object] },
     { index: 201604,
       year: '2016',
       mon: 'April',
       launches: [],
       tbds: [Object] } ] }
```

And then i use this code to attempt to grab values but no matter what i have tried (dot formation, indexes) i cannot get the values to show (i managed to get "undefined-undefined" at one point!

```
  for(var test in data.months){
    console.log(data.months[test]);
    var year = test.index[i].year;
    // var month = data.months.index.mon;
    s += "<p>" + year + "-" + month + "</p>";
  }
    $launchDiv.html(s);
```

Anyone care to help me out and explain how one would handle this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

**Issues**

```
var year = test.index[i].year;
// var month = data.months.index.mon;
```

First, test is a property and not obj. So it should be `data.months[test]`

Second, `index` is a property, and not an array. So `index[i]` is `undefined` so is `index[i].year`. You should rather try `data.months[test].year`

#### Logic

```js
var result = "";
obj.months.forEach(function(item) {
  result += "<p>" + item.year + "-" + item.mon + "</p>";
  item.country1.forEach(function(c) {
    result += getObjectInString(c.l[0]);
  });
  item.country2.forEach(function(c) {
    result += getObjectInString(c.l[0]);
  });
});
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = result;

function getObjectInString(obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var result = "<ul>";
  keys.forEach(function(k) {
    result += "<li>" + k + " : " + obj[k] + "</li>";
  });
  result += "</ul>"
  return result;
}
```

#### Code sample

```js
var obj = {
  months: [{
    index: 201602,
    year: "2016",
    mon: "February",
    country1: [{
      index: 12345678,
      l: [{
        name: "Test1",
        mname: "Test 1",
        net: "February 10, 2016 11:39:00 UTC",
      }]
    }, {
      index: 23456789,
      l: [{
        name: "Test2",
        mname: "Test 2",
        net: "February 10, 2016 11:39:00 UTC",
      }]
    }],
    country2: []
  }, {
    index: 201603,
    year: "2016",
    mon: "March",
    country1: [{
      index: 546547657654,
      l: [{
        name: "Test1",
        mname: "Test 1",
        net: "March 10, 2016 11:39:00 UTC",
      }]
    }],
    country2: []
  }, {
    index: 201604,
    year: "2016",
    mon: "April",
    country1: [],
    country2: [{
      index: 78676756,
      l: [{
        name: "Test1",
        mname: "Test 1",
        net: "April10, 2016 11:39:00 UTC",
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
var result = "";
obj.months.forEach(function(item) {
  result += "<p>" + item.year + "-" + item.mon + "</p>";
  item.country1.forEach(function(c) {
    result += getObjectInString(c.l[0]);
  });
  item.country2.forEach(function(c) {
    result += getObjectInString(c.l[0]);
  });
});
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = result;

function getObjectInString(obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var result = "<ul>";
  keys.forEach(function(k) {
    result += "<li>" + k + " : " + obj[k] + "</li>";
  });
  result += "</ul>"
  return result;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the JSON-structure using index-based looping:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.months.length; i++) {
  var year = data.months[i].year;
  var month = data.months[i].mon;
  s+= '<p>' + year + '-' + month;
}

$launchDiv.html(s);
```

Comment: This works! (although i am sure i tried exactly this at one point). Can you advise how to iterate through the next layer? i.e data.months[i].country1 and country2 i would assume they need an if statement also to detect if there are actually anything within them.

Comment: idealy i would like to list year-month and then within each month display or don't display country1/country2 and the content below that name, mname and net